# In Browser-Solidity, I want to see the messages sent by a contract

Tags: testing, remix

There is good information on this site about writing and ad-hoc testing a contract in [Browser-Solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity). When I use the transaction tab to create my contract and invoke its public functions, I want to see what messages were sent by the contract and to which addresses. Where can these messages be inspected?

**I have seen**

1. [How to quickly test a Solidity function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-quickly-test-a-solidity-function)
2. [Browser Solidity: What does the "Transaction" tab do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/browser-solidity-what-does-the-transaction-tab-do)